How to set connection timeout for Quarkus REST client?
4.1
I have the following config...
%dev.my-auth-api/mp-rest/url=http://my-auth-api-dev:1234/auth
%dev.my-auth-api/mp-rest/scope=javax.inject.Singleton
my-auth-api/mp-rest/url=http://my-auth-api-prod:1234/auth
my-auth-api/mp-rest/scope=javax.inject.Singleton
my-auth-api/mp-rest/connectTimeout=3000

I have put the wrong port on purpose and I keep getting vertx blocked thread warning as below...
{"appTimestamp":"2024-05-29T15:38:01.995Z","loggerName":"io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker","level":"WARN","message":"Thread Thread[#442,checkout-pool-1,5,main] has been blocked for 60360 ms, time limit is 60000 ms","threadName":"vertx-blocked-thread-checker","stackTrace":"io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:221)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller.block(CompletableFuture.java:1864)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3780)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3725)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.waitingGet(CompletableFuture.java:1898)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2072)\n\tat org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.unwrap(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:213)\n\tat org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.method(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:339)\n\tat aaa.bbb.service.MyAuthClient$$QuarkusRestClientInterface.authenticate(Unknown Source)\n\tat aaa.bbb.service.MyAuthClient$$CDIWrapper.authenticate(Unknown Source)\n\tat aaa.bbb.service.MyAuthClient$$CDIWrapper_ClientProxy.authenticate(Unknown Source)\n\tat aaa.bbb.service.PlatformAuthService.authenticate(PlatformAuthService.java:32)\n\tat aaa.bbb.service.PlatformAuthService_Subclass.authenticate$$superforward(Unknown Source)\n\tat aaa.bbb.service.PlatformAuthService_Subclass$$function$$1.apply(Unknown Source)\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:73)\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext$NextAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:97)\n\tat io.smallrye.faulttolerance.FaultToleranceInterceptor.lambda$syncFlow$3(FaultToleranceInterceptor.java:253)\n\tat io.smallrye.faulttolerance.core.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:20)\n\tat io.smallrye.faulttolerance.core.Invocation.apply(Invocation.java:29)\n\tat io.smallrye.faulttolerance.core.retry.Retry.doApply(Retry.java:88)\n\tat io.smallrye.faulttolerance.core.retry.Retry.apply(Retry.java:42)\n\tat io.smallrye.faulttolerance.FaultToleranceInterceptor.syncFlow(FaultToleranceInterceptor.java:255)\n\tat io.smallrye.faulttolerance.FaultToleranceInterceptor.intercept(FaultToleranceInterceptor.java:182)\n\tat io.smallrye.faulttolerance.FaultToleranceInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:70)\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:62)\n\tat io.quarkus.cache.runtime.CacheResultInterceptor$3.apply(CacheResultInterceptor.java:94)\n\tat io.quarkus.cache.runtime.caffeine.CaffeineCacheImpl.getFromCaffeine(CaffeineCacheImpl.java:171)\n\tat io.quarkus.cache.runtime.caffeine.CaffeineCacheImpl$2.get(CaffeineCacheImpl.java:93)\n\tat io.quarkus.cache.runtime.caffeine.CaffeineCacheImpl$2.get(CaffeineCacheImpl.java:90)\n\tat io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualSupplier.get(SlowContextualSupplier.java:21)\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage.subscribe(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:24)\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniBlockingAwait.await(UniBlockingAwait.java:60)\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniAwait.atMost(UniAwait.java:65)\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniAwait.indefinitely(UniAwait.java:46)\n\tat io.quarkus.cache.runtime.CacheResultInterceptor.intercept(CacheResultInterceptor.java:104)\n\tat io.quarkus.cache.runtime.CacheResultInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:30)\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:27)\n\tat aaa.bbb.service.PlatformAuthService_Subclass.authenticate(Unknown Source)\n\tat aaa.bbb.service.SubscriberService.subscribed(SubscriberService.java:60)\n\tat aaa.bbb.service.SubscriberService_Subclass.subscribed$$superforward(Unknown Source)\n\tat aaa.bbb.service.SubscriberService_Subclass$$function$$2.apply(Unknown Source)\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:73)\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:62)\n\tat io.smallrye.faulttolerance.FaultToleranceInterceptor.lambda$syncFlow$3(FaultToleranceInterceptor.java:253)\n\tat io.smallrye.faulttolerance.core.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:20)\n\tat io.smallrye.faulttolerance.core.Invocation.apply(Invocation.java:29)\n\tat io.smallrye.faulttolerance.core.retry.Retry.doApply(Retry.java:88)\n\tat io.smallrye.faulttolerance.core.retry.Retry.apply(Retry.java:42)\n\tat io.smallrye.faulttolerance.FaultToleranceInterceptor.syncFlow(FaultToleranceInterceptor.java:255)\n\tat io.smallrye.faulttolerance.FaultToleranceInterceptor.intercept(FaultToleranceInterceptor.java:182)\n\tat io.smallrye.faulttolerance.FaultToleranceInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:30)\n\tat io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:27)\n\tat aaa.bbb.service.SubscriberService_Subclass.subscribed(Unknown Source)\n\tat aaa.bbb.messaging.CheckoutProcessor.subscribe(CheckoutProcessor.java:92)\n\tat aaa.bbb.messaging.CheckoutProcessor.process(CheckoutProcessor.java:57)\n\tat aaa.bbb.messaging.CheckoutProcessor_ClientProxy.process(Unknown Source)\n\tat aaa.bbb.messaging.CheckoutProcessor_SmallRyeMessagingInvoker_process_bd386abe989418e778612ad8212523c81d813d5e.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.providers.AbstractMediator.lambda$invokeBlocking$10(AbstractMediator.java:171)\n\tat io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualSupplier.get(SlowContextualSupplier.java:21)\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromDeferredSupplier.subscribe(UniCreateFromDeferredSupplier.java:25)\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.withSubscriber(UniSubscribe.java:51)\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.with(UniSubscribe.java:110)\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.with(UniSubscribe.java:88)\n\tat io.vertx.mutiny.core.WorkerExecutor$1.handle(WorkerExecutor.java:105)\n\tat io.vertx.mutiny.core.WorkerExecutor$1.handle(WorkerExecutor.java:103)\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextBase.java:180)\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:277)\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase.lambda$internalExecuteBlocking$2(ContextBase.java:199)\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue.run(TaskQueue.java:76)\n\tat org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)\n\tat org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)\n\tat org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1512)\n\tat org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)\n\tat org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)\n","errorType":"io.vertx.core.VertxException","errorMessage":"Thread blocked"}

I also have the following annotation on the implementation of the client.
@CacheResult(cacheName = "jwt-cache")
@Retry(delay = 3000, jitter= 1000, maxRetries = 4)
@ExponentialBackoff(factor = 2)
public String authenticate(String key, String secret) {
    LOG.debug("Authenticating with auth api.");
    return client.authenticate(new AuthRequest(principal, secret)).getJwt();
}


1: Is the connectTimeout setting correct?
2: Are the annotations correct and/or should they be on the interface?

